# OpenCV Video Capture Get Properties Not Work

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using Python 3.10 in Windows 10 PC to control Logitech C925e Webcam.
I tried to change the cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS (using method [set](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c)) to some value. The brightness of my video stream changed, but when I tried to get value cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNES (using method [get](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aa6480e6972ef4c00d74814ec841a2939)), i always got same value (128.0).

Why this happen?
It's weird because the brightness of my video stream changed, but the value cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNES not changed.

I expect to get same value after set the cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS

Comment: Can you please add your code to set and read the parameter?

Comment: @RolandDeschain Hi, after i tried changed the api parameter in VideoCapture to cv2.CAP_DSHOW, it resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I changed the API parameter in VideoCapture to cv2.CAP_DSHOW, it resolved! In the past, I use the default API which is cv2.MSMF

```
self.camera.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```